# Vue3 + Vite: error handling in production

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I used error handler from vue documentation

https://vuejs.org/guide/best-practices/production-deployment.html#tracking-runtime-errors

```
app.config.errorHandler = (err, instance, info) => {
  console.log(err);
}
```

This works great with dev server, because it shows in which component the error happened and on what line it happened.

```
ReferenceError: foo is not defined
    at ComponentNameWhereErrorHappened.vue:144:15
    at callWithErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:6737:22)
    at callWithAsyncErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:6746:21)
    at Array.job (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:7154:17)
    at flushPreFlushCbs (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:6910:31)
    at flushJobs (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:6951:5)
```

But when I use this code in production, the code gets bundled (using Vite) and then the error handling is not useful anymore. Because the name of files changes and everything happens on line 1.

```
ReferenceError: foo is not defined
    at ComponentNameButNotWhereErrorHappened.b61810f1.js:1:10588
    at Pt (vendor.7753fa93.js:5:656)
    at lt (vendor.7753fa93.js:5:735)
    at Array._ (vendor.7753fa93.js:5:3255)
    at Cl (vendor.7753fa93.js:5:1980)
    at pf (vendor.7753fa93.js:5:2249)
```

Is there a way how to get useful information about runtime errors with production Vue code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by adding `sourcemap: true` to the `vite.config.js`

```
export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    sourcemap: true
  }
})
```